# What is meant by, "the inclusion map X to Y 'extends' to an isometry of X-bar onto Y?

Tags: analysis

What is meant by, "the inclusion map X to Y extends to an isometry of X-bar onto Y?

I can answer this question mechanically by showing that one metric is equal to another, but I do not understand the language.  Is an inclusion map simply an injective mapping; yet it is said to extend to an "onto" mapping?  "Onto" is a word  usually used with bijective mapping.  In the present case, X-bar is the space of equivalence classes of X.  In what sense is "extend" used?  Can someone kindly elaborate?

Comment: Onto by no means implies bijective.

Comment: Is this in the context of the completion of a metric space? If not, what is the context?

Comment: Brian M Scott:   Yes, in the context of a c.m.s.   I am still thinking about the answer Randall kindly made, and I intend to close this, tomorrow.   I take onto to mean that all elements of the range space come from at least one element of the domain space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $X$ is a subset (or sub"thing") of $Y$, the function $i: X \to Y$ given by $i(x)=x$ is typically called an *inclusion*.  So inclusions are injective, but not the other way around necessarily.

In your case, you have a construction called *completion* that takes $X$ and constructs a "desirable" $\overline{X}$ with good properties, and $X$ naturally lies inside $\overline{X}$. So, there is a natural map $e : X \to \overline{X}$ which comes about from the construction of $\overline{X}$.  (I've called it $e$ for ``embedding.")  To say that the inclusion $i: X \to Y$ extends to an isometry of $\overline{X}$ onto $Y$ means that there is an isometry $f: \overline{X} \to Y$ which is onto and has the property that $f \circ e = i$.

Comment: Randall:  I apply your answer as follows:  An inclusion i is a change of membership to that of the including set.   Embedding results from a construction on the element of a set which confers it membership (in my case) in a completion of the set.   In my case of interest, first by embedding, then by an isometry, an element of X is transformed into an equivalence class of Cauchy sequences in a complete metric space and  d(x,y) = rho(x-bar,y-bar).  The result of embedding and the isometry is a change in membership of the element x to the element x-bar, which is an inclusion.      Thank you.

Comment: You say it well.

Comment: Thanks but it took me much effort I regret to say!